# Script to copy range transposed to another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I need to copy a range from the sheet 'Source' to the sheet 'Database' but transposed. It should be the range B1:T9, not the whole sheet. I need to do it with a script as it is going to be a database collected from many reports.

Here is the link 
[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19NOwpxDOMfRMMmJcZs_ht1brPnSEjbxAW4_1zf1Tptw/edit?usp=sharing)

Any ideas how to do it as I didn't find workable code examples for this case

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the issue with the simple copyTo. Didn't know that is can has the syntaxis
copyTo(destination, copyPasteType, transposed)

Google example

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange("A:E").copyTo(sheet.getRange("F1"), spreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES,true);
```